# Show that the derivative of a function is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
x+2x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\\
0&\text{ if }x=0
\end{cases}$$
Show that there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $\{x_n\} \to 0$ as $n$ approaches infinity, such that $g'(x_n)=0\  \forall n$ but $g'(0) \ne 0$.

I calculated
$$g'(x)=4x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+1 ,\text{ if }x\neq0$$

I tried to construct a sequence where $\{x_n\}=\dfrac 1 {2\pi n}$ so that $g'(x_n)=0$, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to prove the question. If this is not right, how can I go about showing it?

Comment: What is $f$? The same as $g$?

Comment: @miracle173 Yes, sorry I mistyped it.

Comment: And what is $g'$ if $x \ne 0$? Did you already calculate it?

Comment: I think $g'$ is $4xsin(1/x)-2cos(1/x)+1$

Comment: Yes, I think you are right

Comment: $g'(x)=\begin{cases}
1+4x\sin\frac{1}{x}-2\cos\frac{1}{x}&\text{ if }x\neq0\\\
1&\text{ if }x=0
\end{cases}$

$g'(\frac{1}{2n\pi})<0$, $g'(\frac{1}{2n\pi+\pi/2})>0$,By intermediate value theorem $\exists \frac{1}{2n\pi+\pi/2}<x_n<\frac{1}{2n\pi}$, $g'(x_n)=0$. I don't know how to construct the concrete $x_n$

Comment: I'm not sure if the question is asking if there $always$ exists such a sequence

Comment: howdy, you are almost there. With your current sequence the derivative with evaluate to -1 not 0.

Comment: the title of our post is strange.

Comment: Feel free to edit it

Comment: @Laura You should post an answer (don't forget to mention $g'$ is continuous for $x>0$).

Comment: If $g'$ is not continuous at 0, can we still apply the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @zhw why do you think your title is more descriptive?

Comment: Because that is what the problem is about. The word "continuous" appears nowhere in the statement of the problem.

Comment: The special thing is that g' is not continous at 0. Otherwise lim g'(x_n)=g'(0). The word continous appears in the title. there is no reason to repeat it in the body of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first summand of your $g'$,
$$4x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
 converges to $0$ if $x$ converges to $0$, because $|4\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)|\le 4$.

$$\cos(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}, 
\text{iff} \;\phi=\pm\frac{\pi}{3}\pm 2k\pi$$

so choose 
$$\frac{1}{x}=\pm\frac{\pi}{3}\pm 2k\pi$$
e.g.
$$x_n=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{3}+ 2n\pi}$$

But in a similar way you can construct sequences $x_n$ that converge to a  value different to $0$.

$$g'(0)=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1-x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=1$$
So the constructed sequence shows that the derivate $g'$ of $g$ is not continous at $x=0$.

Comment: But if we plug $x_n=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{3}+ 2n\pi}$ in to the equation of $$g'(x)=4x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+1 ,\text{ if }x\neq0$$, we do not get $g'(x_n)=0$, that is we do not have $sin \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{3}+ 2n\pi}=0$

Comment: you get $g'(x_n)= \frac{4}{\frac{\pi}{3}+ 2n\pi}\sin (\frac{\pi}{3}+ 2n\pi)$. This converges to $0$